# Bootstrap 4, can't set width of cards by exact percentage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Check this [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/TR1jIXZTj2). Unless I missed a gotcha somewhere in the doc, I should be able to manually via css set the width of `card` elements. I am using the cards within `card-deck` but if that is what's messing this up, again there's nothing in the docs about it...

Anyway, as you can see from the codeply, the width appears to be completely ignored... even though upon element inspection it shows correctly, the final computed value is very different.

For example on a large screen, all 6 cards show upon  1 row, disobeying the `width: 25%`. On small screens, 1 card does take up 50%, but the next card is bumped to the next row, rather than 2 side by side

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">4 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">5 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">6 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



.card {
    width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card {
        width: 33%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .card {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point `width` property will not for `.card-deck .card`. You have to write `width` using `flex-basis` and `max-width`. Code is below.

```
.card {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 576px){
  .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: calc(50% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
    max-width: calc(33.3333% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px); /* Remove margin from total card width */
  }
}
```

Bootstrap set `.card-deck .card` css property `margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;` that why card isn't going full width. At this point need to remove `margin width` from total card `width`.

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/gOpBQjQ).

It will not good because bootstrap card design is difference. You have to change `html` for above design it will no need to use custom css property.

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/rNVqQqM).

**Edited**

Bootstrap remove `margin` from `.card` class if window width less than or equal to `575.98px` Same for `.card-deck` class remove `display: flex;flex-flow: row wrap;`. If you want two cards in per row in small devices. Do like this.

```
.card {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

Add `d-flex flex-wrap` class with `card-deck`.

```
<div class="card-deck d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
```

I update the [pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/gOpBQjQ). Below is complete **HTML** and **CSS** code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">4 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">5 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">6 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-deck .card {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(33.3333% - 30px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
  }
}
```

Comment: i can't use the grid layout (your 2nd solution), because the whole purpose of using the cards is to align height & footers with different body texts and such... The 1st solution isn't working for me I'm afraid. On the pen, if you make it a mobile width, the card with is 50% but there's only 1 per row, the second card gets pushed off...

Comment: @james I change the pen also update ans please check.

Comment: Thank you!!! It's getting closer, but for whatever reason, on mobile width, once again the card is 1 per row, the second is pushed off. To be clear, on mobile, smallest device, I'm using the `flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px); max-width: calc(50% - 30px);` settings. Basically I want the smallest device to have 2 cards per row

Comment: @james I Update ans and change pen. Please check.

Comment: ok super weird, but even though it was working in your pen, it still wasn't working on my development mode, I was using Chrome & checking against responsive devices, all mobile devices showed 1 row. HOWEVER, I did some tweaking, and found that if I added `.card-deck { flex-direction: row; }` then this fixes the problem. I don't have any experience with `flexbox` however, does this seem like the right course of action? So far it doesn't look like anything else has been affected

Comment: You should add `.card-deck{display: flex;flex-direction: row;flex-wrap: wrap;}`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the flexbox used on card-deck card is `flex:1 0 0%` which means cards won't "grow" to width. You can override this by using flex-fill on the cards. Also use `.card-deck .card` specificity in the CSS selectors.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card mb-4 flex-fill">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        ... (more cards)
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/uqFnzcSLxU

Comment: this does work with one gotcha... in the ply, if you only have 3 cards, at the 50% width, 2 sit nicely together on one row, the last one expands to be a monstrous card at 100% width of teh second row, rather than 50% width again...